# Why is the Window not loading ? [Win32]

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

Hi I am an Beginner learning DirectX 11 Api I have seen tutorial on Youtube and implemented this Wrapper for Windows But the Window is lot Loading The only debug string I get is just the Register Class Failed string in the INIT_WINDOw method . Nothing else Pops up . PLease help me with this .
DX_Wrapper.cpp

```cpp
#include "Headers/Dx_Wrapper.h"

//Global One For Defining __stdcall for WindowProc
namespace
{
    Wrapper* g_wrapper = nullptr;
}

//Main WINDOW Message processing Window Procedure 
LRESULT CALLBACK WINDOWPROC(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    if (g_wrapper) return g_wrapper->MessageProcedure(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    else return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
//Constructor For the Instance
Wrapper::Wrapper(HINSTANCE hinstance)
{
    m_hinstance = hinstance;
    m_hwnd = NULL;
    m_winheight = 600;
    m_winwidth = 800;
    m_wintitle = L"DirectX";
    m_winstyles = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
    g_wrapper = this;
}
Wrapper::~Wrapper()
{

}

//Window Loop Manager Attached to the WINDOWPROC function
int32_t Wrapper::Run()
{
    
    MSG message = { 0 };

    while (WM_QUIT != message.message)
    {
        //Message Check If Quit 
        if (PeekMessage(&message, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessage(&message);
        }
        //If Not Quit
        else
        {
            UPDATE_FRM(5.5f);

        }
    }

    return static_cast<int>(message.wParam);
}

bool Wrapper::Init()
{

    if (!INIT_WINDOW() == true)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

LRESULT  Wrapper::MessageProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);

    }
}

void Wrapper::UPDATE_FRM(float delta_time)
{
    
}
void Wrapper::RENDER_FRM(float delta_time)
{

}

//Registering Classical Windows Class Function 
bool Wrapper::INIT_WINDOW()
{
    //THE CLASS REGISTERING STUFF

    WNDCLASSEX win_class;
    
    win_class.cbClsExtra = 0;
    win_class.hInstance = m_hinstance;
    win_class.cbWndExtra = 0;
    win_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    win_class.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    win_class.lpfnWndProc = WINDOWPROC;
    win_class.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    win_class.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    win_class.lpszClassName = L"dx_main_class";
    win_class.hCursor = 0;
    RegisterClassEx(&win_class);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&win_class))
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"Registering Class Failed");
        return false;
    }

    RECT r = {0,0,m_winwidth,m_winheight};

    AdjustWindowRect(&r, m_winstyles, FALSE);

    uint_fast16_t f_width = r.right - r.left;
    uint_fast16_t f_height = r.bottom - r.top;

    uint_fast16_t f_width_final = uint_fast16_t(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2 - f_width / 2);
    uint_fast16_t f_height_final = uint_fast16_t(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2 - f_height / 2);



    m_hwnd = CreateWindow(L"dx_main_class", m_wintitle, m_winstyles, f_width_final, f_height_final, f_width, f_height, NULL, NULL, m_hinstance, NULL);

    if (!m_hwnd)
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"Window Could Not be Created ");
        return false;
    }

    ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_SHOW);

    return true;
}
```

DX_Wrapper.h

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(HINSTANCE hinstance);
    virtual ~Wrapper();
    int32_t Run();
    virtual bool Init();
    virtual LRESULT  MessageProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);
    virtual void  UPDATE_FRM(float delta_time) = 0;
    virtual void  RENDER_FRM(float delta_time) = 0;

protected:

    HWND m_hwnd = nullptr;
    HINSTANCE m_hinstance = nullptr;
    uint_fast16_t m_winwidth = 0;
    uint_fast16_t m_winheight = 0;
    LPCWSTR m_wintitle = L"";
    DWORD m_winstyles = 0;

protected:

    bool INIT_WINDOW();

};
```

This is the Main Application CPP file

```cpp
#include "Headers/Dx_Wrapper.h"
class Application : public Wrapper
{
public:
    Application(HINSTANCE hinstance);
    

    bool Init() override;
    void UPDATE_FRM(float delta_time) override;
    void RENDER_FRM(float delta_time) override;
};
Application::Application(HINSTANCE hinstance) : Wrapper(hinstance)
{

}

bool Application::Init()
{
    return Wrapper::Init();
    
}
void Application::UPDATE_FRM(float delta_time)
{

}
void Application::RENDER_FRM(float delta_time)
{

}
int32_t WINAPI WinMain(__in HINSTANCE hinstance, __in_opt HINSTANCE hprevinstance, __in LPSTR cmdline, __in int cmdshow)
{
    Application m_app(hinstance);
    if (!m_app.Init()) return 1;


    return m_app.Run();
}
```

My Problem is The OutputDebugString Just shows The Registering class failed string from the INIT_WINDOW function . I have no clue why it is wrong . The Window is not running .

Comment: You are trying to register the class twice. If you want to know more read the docs. They will tell you how and when to call GetLastError to find out why any api calls failed.

Comment: Follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexw): *"`cbSize`: The size, in bytes, of this structure. **Set this member to `sizeof(WNDCLASSEX)`**."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you called twice `RegisterClassEx` function, so you need to delete the first call:

```
//RegisterClassEx(&win_class);
if (!RegisterClassEx(&win_class))
{
    OutputDebugString(L"Registering Class Failed");
    return false;
}
```

Then you need to set each member of [`WNDCLASSEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexw).

So you can refer to the following code:

```
WNDCLASSEX win_class;
win_class.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
win_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
win_class.lpfnWndProc = WINDOWPROC;
win_class.cbClsExtra = 0;
win_class.cbWndExtra = 0;
win_class.hInstance = m_hinstance;
win_class.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
win_class.hCursor = 0;
win_class.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
win_class.lpszMenuName = NULL;
win_class.lpszClassName = L"dx_main_class";
win_class.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
```